# Telegram API inline request_contact

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

Is it possible to use request_contact in inline button or with api request? I know about keyboard, but it doesn't suit me.

Answer (score 6):

No, it isn't. Take a look at [InlineKeyboardButton](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton) and [KeyboardButton](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#keyboardbutton). If you compare them you'll see that **InlineKeyboardButton** has no **request_contact** field.